# Easiest way to find duplicate content in string

Tags: jquery, string

I want to use Johann Burkard's jQuery highlight plugin to highlight a term called "stack" in a div. But there are more than one "stack" strings found in the div. I need to highlight only the first instance of this string. How to avoid the duplicate string using jquery?

Comment: Are you highlighting a div or a text string? The question is unclear. What method did you try already that didn't work for you?

Comment: @GregPettit I need to highlight a text string in a div. I use Johann Burkard jquery highlight plugin. This plugin works fine but also highlight the duplicate terms also. so i do i avoid duplicate text?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='div1'>
stack stack
<div>

$('#div1').html($('#div1').text().replace('stack','<span style="background-color:blue">stack</span>'));
```

Comment: Looks good to me! Don't even need a plugin. Kai is just adding an inline style for the purpose of illustration, but you should probably add a class.